# Connect two virtualbox machines on a same host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, lan

I have a virtual machine attached to NAT. It has the default IP 10.0.2.15. Now I create another machine but the new machine still has the same IP address 10.0.2.15. Is there a way that I can keep the network setting for the first machine, change the second machine's IP to something like 10.0.3.15 and make those two machine able to ping to each other (as in a LAN network) ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change NAT to internal network on both of the machines. So they can communicate with each other.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use "NAT Network" instead of "NAT"

This worked for me with VirtualBox version 5.2.22 and Redhat 7.5.
The VM's had different IP's and both had access to internet.

For, both VM's :

1. Turn them off
2. Right-click the VM -> setting -> network:

   - Select "NAT Network" in "attached to"
   - Select "Allow VMs" in "Promiscuous mode" (advanced chevron)
3. Turn them on
4. Use `ifconfig` command to find out each VM IP. in my case: `10.0.2.4` and `10.0.2.5`

[More explanation here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)

The following table provides an overview of the most important networking modes..

```
    |           | VM <-> Host | VM1 <-> VM2 | VM -> Internet | VM <- Internet |
    +-----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+
    | HostOnly  |     Yes     |     Yes     |      No        |       No       |
    | Internal  |     No      |     Yes     |      No        |       No       |
    | Bridged   |     Yes     |     Yes     |      Yes       |       Yes      |
    | NAT       |     No      |     No      |      Yes       |  Port forward  |
    | NATNet    |     No      |     Yes     |      Yes       |  Port forward  |
    +-----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+
```

NB: If you want to connect to the VM's with tty, you need to do IP forwarding.

In the VirtualBox config: File -> Preference -> Network -> double-click NAT network -> port forwarding -> Add a rule: host IP 127.0.0.1, port 23 (or whatever to put in tty), Guest IP (the VM IP, example : 10.0.2.5), guest port 22

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.